# Adding another RemoteApp server to existing domain

Tags: remoteapp, licensing

Just a simple question.
We presently have one Windows 2008 R2 RemoteApp server in place and all is licensed and working well.

We are now in process of adding another RemoteAPP server to our existing domain but it will be running Windows Server 2012 R2.

My question is, after installing the role and rebooting the server, will it cause any issues with our current RemoteApp setup? I'm a little worried to install the second server and after a reboot find some silly error on the orginal server when staff try to login to launch there RemoteApp web applications saying "blah blah is unavailable, etc."

Will they be two entities and have no issues working side by side after the installation without any interaction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will they be two entities and have no issues working side by side after the installation without any interaction?

Yes, they will be separate entities without any interaction on the RemoteApp side.  Of course they'll be on the same domain and have that interaction just like any member of a domain, but as far as RemoteApp there will be no conflict.

If you had a terminal/RDS farm setup and wanted to add another Remote Desktop Session Host (RDSH) server then you would have to tweak a lot more on the setup.  As far as RemoteApp is concerned, unless you truly want to span apps across multiple servers you should be able to add the 2012 server, join it to the domain, and create your Remote Apps just like you did on the 2008 box and push them to people.  I will note, however, that you can't distribute the RemoteApps the same way that 2008 let you, so see [this article](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/vdi-articles/general/distribution-of-remote-apps-and-desktops-in-windows-server-2012.html) for a good guide on how to get around it.  Specifically the section entitled **Distributing Remote Apps and Desktops with Windows Server 2012**

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So licensing will also not be an issue? I will just need to purchase some new licesnes for the other server and install them. The existing 2008 R2 setup won't get upset with the new one and its licensing then automatically stop distributing licenses to existing clients?

Comment: "I will just need to purchase some new licesnes for the other server and install them." That is correct.  Make sure you have the number of CALs you need for however many users/computers will be accessing these RemoteApps too.  I'm sure that's what you meant when you said licensing, but just thought I'd reiterate.  And no, the 2008 box will not stop distributing licenses or Apps to clients.

Comment: Any time my friend.